# Subtracting pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas

Apologies I'm a python noob and I'm super rusty. Just getting back into code. Need help.

I have a dataframe (df) that looks like this:

```
        2020-10-21 2020-09-30 2020-08-31 2020-07-31 2020-06-30 2020-05-29
close   513.19     470.11     325.10     253.91     253.54     179.48
```

I'm trying to add a new column that calculates the difference between the most recent column (2020-10-21) and the last column (2020-05-29).

```
df['Val_Diff'] = df[0] - df[5]

print(df)
```

When it runs I'm getting the following error.

```
KeyError: 0
```

What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about columns' index (instead of name). use `df.iloc[:,0] - df.iloc[:,5]`.

`iloc` receive index while `loc` receive column name.
Also, `loc` and `iloc` are looking for `[rows, columns]`, hence to choose all rows in a specific column: `.iloc[:, column_index]`

Comment: thanks. now I'm getting this error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: that means that your columns are parsed as string instead of float. Check online how to change their types using `.astype()` method